# Jest TransformIgnorePatterns all node_modules for React-Native Preset

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm New to jest,

After setting-up jest config in my project's - package.json,

**Package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(react-native-cookies)/)"]
  },
```

i already Tried this for ignoring all node modules:-

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules"]
```

But not working For me

and **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

My LoginScreen-Test.js Code:-

**TestCase**

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import LoginScreen from '../src/components/LoginScreen';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const hello = renderer.create(<LoginScreen/>).toJSON();
  expect(hello).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

i begin to run --> npm test or npm test -- -u

it reflects me with following error:-

**Terminal Output**

> FAIL  **tests**/LoginScreen-test.js   ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> /Users/Documents/Projects/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.ios.js:31
>   get isTesting(): boolean {
>                  ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
>   at Object.get Platform [as Platform] (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:111:27)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-cookies/index.js:9:17)
> ```

I want to Ignore All Node modules by TransformIgnorePattern, but seems it is not Working for my React-Native Preset,..

Looking for the Helpful Answer...

Comment: Have you tried to run it with `--no-cache`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle 
i tried like this  `"test": "jest --no-cache"`  in my package.json also . but nothing new done with that ..

Comment: Seeing the same issue as you, using React Native version `0.56.0` and Jest `23.6.0`.  There doesn't seem to be an answer for it anywhere except for some "wipe your dependencies and reinstall"... that never helps for me (even wiping the lock of course)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This error shows that "react-native" has not been transformed:
`react-native/Libraries/Utilities/Platform.ios.js:31`

`"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules"]` won't work because it is pretty much the default behavior.

Have you tried using the [official recommendation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization) config? It should look something like this for your project:

`"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native-cookies)/)"
]`

the `?!` is important because it means ignore everything in the node_modules EXCEPT for `react-native` and `react-native-cookies`.

Comment: The crucial part for me was that you want the pattern to *not* match the target file/folder. I think the linked example shows this wel: https://regex101.com/r/JsLIDM/1

Answer (score 10):

This is the correct config in 2023

```
   "transformIgnorePatterns": [
     "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native(-.*)?|@react-native(- 
     community)?)/)"
    ]
```

Comment: Any official source for this? Is it guaranteed that _all_ packages matched will require transformation? Or is there no downside to not ignoring them?

Answer (score 1):

I hame the same issue. This solution above doesnt work for me.

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@testing-library/react-native',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native(-.*)?|@react-native(-community)?)/)',
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    './node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js',
    '<rootDir>/jest.setup.js',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.svg': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/svgMock.js',
  },
  collectCoverage: false,
  coverageDirectory: '__coverage__',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '.*.svg', '.*.png'],
}
```